# Unlock ASUS Transformer Tablet

Tags: lock-screens, asus-eee-pad-transformer, locked-out

My ASUS Transformer TF700 worked fine and I did not put in any unlock code to open it.  One day the initial screen showed a keypad and invited me to put in the unlock code.  I read you can simultaneously push the power and volume buttons and do a "WIPE" that takes it back to Factory Default Settings.  I have tried this repeatedly- holding for 5 -  20 seconds -since some postings indicate that 5 and 10 seconds bring different levels of "wipe."  I have not had any luck with the ASUS Website.

I know this is pretty simple compared to all the "Super Geek" stuff I see on this site.  However I can not even aspire to be a "Mediocre Geek" if I cannot unlock my tablet.

Comment: I would contact ASUS for assistance.

Comment: I second @Ramhound's advice.  In addition, this would probably be more appropriate on the Android Enthusiasts SE site.

Comment: May sound a stupid question: But did you turn off your tablet before trying to enter Recovery Mode using that key combo? It works only when the device is powered down. // I also added the `locked-out` tag to your question; you might wish to visit [its tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/locked-out/info) for some first-aid.